Removing Git from a project in VS Code
I'm working on a web project in VS Code and I tried using Github for versioning. I originally used the "Source Control" extension on the left side, but since I tried using it so late into my project. I was met with an error that there are too many changes to upload to the repo. Now i'm jsut looking to remove this functionality from my project.
I saw a similar post on here and the top comment said that by opening the "command line" I think it is called, not the terminal. (Cmnd+shft+P) you can hit "Git: Close Repository" and it works, but then whenever I click on one of the "package-lock.json" files in my file explorer within VS Code, the repo opens again. Is there just a way to close it for good lol?

Your project should have directory called .git - just delete that.

You want version control. It doesn't have to be git, but you want something. I would not abandon it because of IDE having trouble, I would use the command line tools to get it set up to work in the IDE. ("terminal" and "command line" are basically synonyms in the context you're talking about)

As @SiKing mentioned on his comment, You should delete a folder named .git.
It is usually a hidden folder. It may not be visible on your project folder.
You can see it by cd into your project folder and running this command.
ls -la

To remove it cd into your project folder and run this command on your terminal :
rm -rf .git

-rf flag recursively deletes files and folders

If you don't know how to cd into a folder.
You can use VSCode's terminal, it usually opens up with your project directory as its current path.
or
If you have git-bash installed, you can go to your project folder using file explorer and, right-click and select open git Bash here option.
